# Sintaxis SQL Server a Oracle [Crear Usuario]

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Hola estaba buscando como cambiar esta sintaxis de sql server a oracle y aún no comprendo la estructura que tiene oracle en sus bd.

La sintaxis sql server:

```
USE [BD]
GO
/****** Object:  User [pepe]    Script Date: 06/05/2017 10:17:14 ******/
CREATE USER [pepe] FOR LOGIN [pepe] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
```

y tengo entendido que en oracle sería:

```
USE BD
create user pepe identified by pepe;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO pepe;
```

Y no sé como seguir migrando la parte del 'WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]'. Espero que me puedan ayudar por favor.

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu duda? ¿Crear un usuario con una contraseña específica o hacer la migración del schema?

Comment: En Oracle el usuario es en si mismo un esquema.

Answer (score 2):

Vas bien...

```
CREATE USER pepe IDENTIFIED BY contrasenia_de_pepe;
```

Es decir, `CREATE USER <nombre de usuario> IDENTIFIED BY <contraseña del usuario>`.

Tal y como se explica en la documentación de Oracle de [`CREATE USER`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8003.htm):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]